# Message boxes OSX Guideline

Tags: c++, macos, qt, qt4

this should be easy.

I am trying to implement an OS-independent class for message boxes and dialogs (e.g., QMessageBox, QFileDialog).

The objective is having **native look and feel** on each platform, but on OSX this means that I should have sheets coming down the active window.

Are there any Qt recommendations I could read about this issue?

Cheers!

Comment: Is your question about the general topic of OS-specific dialogs, or about displaying sheets on OS X?

Comment: It is OS-specific: I'd like to create my own messageboxes with Qt, but they feel not really "native"...

Answer (score 0):

This [article](http://doc.qt.digia.com/qq/qq18-macfeatures.html) describes making a message box behave as a sheet on OSX using Qt.

(Unfortunately, the article is 7 years old.  I implemented it, and its not working.  But I am using show() but this [article](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6754049/setting-parent-for-a-qmessagebox) says to use open() or set the modality.  So I can't vouch for it until I debug it.)